# Possible to add a translation to a gettext (*.po) catalog using PHP?

Tags: php, gettext

I am adding localization to a website. This process could be fully automated if I could simply add the translation to the .po file through PHP, but I can't seem to find a library which allows this (a PHP version of POEdit for example).

What I've been doing, since the HTML largely follows the same format throughout, is run each phtml file (They are actually Zend Framework views if it makes a difference) through a class I wrote to isolate the original english text, assign it an index (`page.block.1`), and write a `<?php echo _('page.block.1'); ?>` function while wrapping the original text in HTML comments. I then manually open POEdit, check for new strings to be translated, and cut/paste the commented text from the phtml file to POEdit.

This is very time consuming. Assuming I could use a PHP library to add a new translation, I have both the index and the string ready, so it would not only eliminate human error but also complete the task in seconds rather than hours.

Does such a class exist, for PHP or even python/perl? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: It does not exist. Parsing .po files is no big deal. But gettext [isn't used widely enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242478/php-translation-frontend-similar-to-rosetta) for PHP applications, so nobody bothered to write a modification library. The best approach is still to update the template .pot by invoking `xgettext`.

Comment: @mario - Thanks, that's too bad but I understand. I thought maybe I just didn't know what to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is much simpler way especially if you're using [Zend_Translate gettext adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.adapter.html).

You can use translate functions directly in your .phtml files like this:

```
<label><?php echo $this->translate('some fancy text'); ?><label>
```

And then use the [xgettext](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/gettext/xgettext-Invocation.html) utility to create .po file from your .phtml files. The invocation of the xgettext would be something like this:

```
xgettext -o nameOfTheGeneratedPOFile.po --keyword=translate -L php
```

Then you can use the POEdit to translate the .po file and [msgfmt](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/gettext/msgfmt-Invocation.html) to create the .mo file.

Check out the [Zend_Translate documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.introduction.html) for more info on how to use it.

Comment: Even though this doesn't allow for automation, it's probably the best answer I'm going to get. Next time I opt to do localization for a large site consisting of mostly static HTML I'll better research my options. Not a fan of `ctrl+x` `ctrl+v` for 6 hours..

Comment: The highest level of automation you can get from this approach is to create a script that will go through all .phtml files, create a new .po file and merge it with existing .po file.

Comment: Right on, that's essentially what I've done. It wouldn't be so bad if it weren't a key based PO file (rather than English text as the key). We didn't want to break the other translations if we update the English text, considering how expensive technical translations are in multiple languages! So this nets me a PO file with thousands of keys ('section.page.head.block1') that need to be filled in with English text via POEdit.